# What does the alpha channel on a back buffer do?

Tags: opengl, graphics, graphics-programming, srgb

I see that e.g. in OpenGL it is possible to create a back buffer with an alpha channel (RGBA8888). What's the effect/advantage over having an RGB888 back buffer?

Comment: It's actually very likely that RGB888 is actually a RGBA8888 buffer. as it's cheaper to access data that's aligned to 4 byte boundaries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the destination's alpha (backbuffer) as a factor in blending functions such as `GL_DST_ALPHA` and `GL_ONE_MINUS_DST_ALPHA`.

This, among other things, lets you do front-to-back transparency/blending.

On some platform this also lets you have transparent windows and overlays that use the front buffer's alpha value.

Comment: That means until I need these special use cases, I can initialize my back buffer without alpha channel?

Comment: If you want. It should work either way. A lot of GPU drivers will use 32bits either way due to memory alignment constraints.